# Showing Blank Lists [] [] [] [] while writing the file contents to a file in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, nltk

I want to (read) the book ( in a text file), as it is in its current form. The format of book is in text file, like

> In Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, volume 9, pages
>   541–544, 1958. [314] R. De Nicola and F. Vaandrager. Three logics for
>   branching bisimulation (extended abstract). In 5th Annual IEEE
>   Symposium on Logic in Computer Science (LICS), pages 118–129. IEEE
>   Computer Society Press, Springer-Verlag, 1990. [315] X. Nicollin and
>   J.-L. Richier and J. Sifakis and J. Voiron. ATP: an algebra for timed
>   processes. In IFIP TC2 Working Conference on Programming Concepts and
>   Methods, pages 402–427. North Holland, 1990.

The book can be any book (.txt file) with 400 or more pages.

What I am trying to do is that, first of all I split each sentence of the book (txt file) to a list using `sent_tokenize`. Thereafter, now the file is having a list of list of sentences with respect to the input text file and I need to write the file (as it is with list of list of sentences) into a new file.

The program is executed successfully, but when I open the new generated file, which is suppose to contain the sentence of lists, it prints blank [][][]. I hope there is some encoding issue. This is the output looking like

[image]
I am interested to figure out this issue. Any help is appreciated.

The code whatever I have tried is as follows:

```
import nltk, re
import string
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer, sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg, stopwords
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

def remove_punctuation(from_text):
    table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
    stripped = [w.translate(table) for w in from_text]
    return stripped

def preprocessing():
    with open("F:\\Pen Drive 8 GB\\PDF\\Code\\Books Handbooks\\Books Handbooks Text\\b1.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
         tokens_sentences = sent_tokenize(f.read())
         tokens = [[word.lower() for word in line.split()] for line in tokens_sentences]
         global stripped_tokens
         stripped_tokens = [remove_punctuation(i) for i in tokens]
         sw = (stopwords.words('english'))
         filter_set = [[token for token in sentence if (token.lower() not in sw and token.isalnum() and token.isalpha() and re.findall(r"[^_ .'\"-[A-Za-z]]+", token))] for sentence in stripped_tokens]
    lemma = WordNetLemmatizer()
    lem = []
    for w in filter_set:
        lem.append([wi for wi in map(lemma.lemmatize, w)])
    return lem
result = preprocessing()
with open('F:\\Pen Drive 8 GB\\PDF\\Code\\Books Handbooks\\Books Handbooks Text\\b1list.txt', "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for e in result[:]:  
        f.write(str(e))
preprocessing()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Done. Please see my edit @daniel.

Comment: Since you felt it necessary to specifically append "*write to a text file*" to your title and include the code to do so in your [mcve], does that mean that you get the desired result if you print it normally to screen? In other words: you checked and this only occurs when writing to a text file?

Comment: Yeah @usr2564301. I have checked by executing the same. The program is behaving normal. But, nothing is there in the output. Please see the screen shot of the output as an attachment.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to remove the "writing to file" section of your code and the title of your question, then, as it distracts from the actual issue. Currently, your title reads as if *that* is the problem.

Comment: @Could you please highlight why is it behaving like this!

Comment: We still don't understand what your problem actually is. What output do you get when you print to the screen?

Comment: @Daniel. The screenshot of the output is attached in above. I am getting blank lists in the generated file (the input texts are missing). In `input` I am giving a text file, but in the `output` instead of getting texts of list of lists sentences. I am getting only blank lists. I am interested why this is the issue?

Comment: One thing will help me. Save the text written in the above in a text file and read the same file, then separate all the sentences into list of lists. Thus, there after there will be the file with list of lists. I want this to save  the updated results file (list of lists) in a new file. The code at where I am strucking is shown above.

Comment: This is unclear. The simplest explanation of why you are writing seemingly empty lists to a file is that the lists that you are writing are actually empty. Have you checked that the lists are nonempty. What is you replace `f.write(str(e))` by `if len(e) > 0: f.write(str(e))` ? My guess is that you will get a blank output file, which shows that your lists are not what you think that they are. Writing to the file reveals the error, but it is unlikely to be the error itself. Without a [mcve] (which would require the input) it is hard to say more than that.

Comment: Thanks. @John, when I'm printing the same in the console by print(str(e), it shows me the text embedded in list. However, if I do the same and write it's contents into a file. It's printing blank list.

Comment: Perhaps you are seeing an encoding problem. Notepad doesn't do Unicode very well. What if you open the file with a different text editor? Again, without a [mcve] it is hard to say much.

Comment: Okay I will update it soon!